# Can I invert a hessian matrix using gauss jordan elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, hessian-matrix, gaussian-elimination

I don't understand why you can't invert a hessian matrix using gauss jordan method. Can't you integrate or differentiate an entire row (because they are linear operators) and then subtract/add/swap?

To clarify, I mean inverting the generic hessian formulation before it is applied to any function. In this way, I can get the hessian inverse so I can apply it to other functions. otherwise, I'd need to calculate hessian of a function and then invert, which takes a larger time complexity.

Comment: No, integration and differentiation are not allowed as row operations.

Comment: I think there is no reason why you can't invert a _real square invertible_ matrix using Gauss-Jordan. Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: You can invert using Gauss Jordan. I have no idea what integrating or differentiating a row means in this context.

Comment: @copper.hat How do I invert using that if I cannot integrate the hessian?

Comment: @Somos I am talking about inverting the hessian itself, not the hessian applied onto some function

Comment: Why would you want to integrate the Hessian and what has that got to do with inverting it? Your question is missing some context.

Comment: @copper.hat how do you apply row reduction then? You cannot multiply a derivative to make it another derivative.

Comment: @JobHunter69 You can multiply by the ratio of two derivatives, since $f'(x) = g'(x) [f'(x)/g'(x)]$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.